# django form to display a dropdown list causes typeError

Tags: django, forms, typeerror

In my app, I need the user to select an integer value from a drop down list.I thought I would create a form for this as below

```
class CIForm(forms.Form):
    intervaloption = forms.ChoiceField(choices = [x for x in range(1,10)],label='Days taken')
```

however ,when I tried to display this using as_p() in django shell,it threw a TypeError

```
In [29]: f= CIForm()

In [30]: f
Out[30]: <__main__.CIForm object at 0xaa93eec>

In [31]: print f.as_p()

ERROR: An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line statement', (41, 0))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
...
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I can't make out what I am doing wrong ..can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [ChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField.choices) documentation:

> choices
>
> An iterable (e.g., a list or tuple) of 2-tuples to use as
>   choices for this field. This argument accepts the same formats as the
>   choices argument to a model field. See the model field reference
>   documentation on choices for more details.

Something like this should work:

```
class CIForm(forms.Form):
    intervaloption = forms.ChoiceField(choices = [(str(x), str(x)) for x in range(1,10)], label='Days taken')
```